# mysql data loading error (date order)

Tags: mysql, date

I have a large .txt file including 20 millions of lines of strings like:

```
"CS1221|123.10|17.02.2012 09:10:23,5676"
```

The first is customer id, then separated by "|" we have $ amount of transactions and finally date and time (dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss,ssss).

I am trying to load it to Mysql table but it isn't accepting this ordering as `TIMESTAMP` (it accepts YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss,ssss)

Is there any piece of code written in mysql that helps me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the STR_TO_DATE method to convert that date format. Try something like this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('17.02.2012 09:10:23,5676', '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s,%f');
```

Should yield:

```
2012-02-17 09:10:23.567600
```

So your INSERT query would look something like:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (all, relevant, field_names) VALUES ("CS1221", "123.10", STR_TO_DATE('17.02.2012 09:10:23,5676', '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s,%f'));
```